# Can the intersection of triangles produce a parallelogram?

Tags: geometry

I came across a question asking for a list of figures  that can be formed by the intersection of two arbitrary triangles. Attempts showed that we can get at least, lines, rectangles, squares, and triangles of course. I also found something I think is not on the list. Intuitively it looks like:

> **Observation.** a parallelogram cannot be obtained by the intersection of two triangles

since the sides never meet at a point to determine a triangle. How can I go about proving this?

Comment: Your post indicates that you have already produced *some* parallelograms, such as squares and rectangles. You can similarly produce a parallelogram that is not a square or rectangle.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you! Of course. I was working with an exception. (the particular parallelogram I had drawn inside a particular triangle was such that no second triangle could be build using the parallelogram.)

Comment: I can build a parallelogram of I think arbitrary shape whose interior is the intersection of the interiors of two triangles. Could try to describe it in words in an answer, but it should not be necessary: if you can build a rectangle, then you should be able to build a non-rectangular parallelogram. Just apply a **shear** to everything.

Comment: That is very interesting. That means that you would also be able to build a non-rectangular parallelogram using overlapping squares (since you can build a rectangle by intersecting them). I think the elementary book I'm working with wouldn't allow the use of such transformations, but it's good to learn about them in advance. Thanks André.

Comment: That doesn't work for constructing things out of squares. If you apply a shear to a triangle, you get a triangle, but if you apply a (non-trivial) shear to a square, you don't get a square.

Comment: aha! That makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below. The blue triangle was formed by rotating the red one 180 degrees, and then shifting. The purple area is a parallelogram.

[image]